# How to filter array of dates with textfields in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, filtering, nsdatecomponents

I have two textfields one is containing  "From Date" and another one is containing "To date" based on that how to filter array of dates.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code that you tried!

Comment: Parse textfield strings into dates and then filter dates that are lowe than start date and higher then end date.

Comment: Your requirement is not understandable completely, could you please add more details with the help of some code too !!!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669902/nspredicate-to-filter-between-two-dates-of-nsstring-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669902/nspredicate-to-filter-between-two-dates-of-nsstring-type)

Comment: i didn't Try other code my requirements is i have two textfields. one textfield is "From date" Textfield and another  Textfield Is "TO date". i am getting array of dates from server once user entered From and To date the events array should be filtered with From and to dates. @ipatel @ K.R.Saravana Kumar

Answer (score 0):

you have two date first is starting date and other in ending date and other is date that check in between of start and end date or not..

```
          let format = DateFormatter()
            format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"// before formate 
             let date_selected = format.date(from: date)
            format.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"// change related to my format
           let seldate_selected = format.string(from: date_selected!)
            let dt = format.date(from: seldate_selected)
          let str_dat = format.date(from: startDate)
            let end_dat = format.date(from: endDate)

            if dt! >= str_dat! && dt! <= end_dat!
            {
              print("selected date is not in between start date and end date ")
           } 
         else 
          {
             print("selected date is not in between start date and end date ")
          }
```

Comment: let date_selected = format.date(from: date) in this line of code from where you are taking date?